# reCaptcha V2 force text display

Tags: recaptcha

Is there any way to make the google reCaptcha V2 always display text instead of the image challenge?

Will the V1 be deprecated?

Right now sometimes it shows the text challenge and other times the image one which I find really unaesthetic.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem, where I would like to be able to force text only validation...